# How to get a background-color on a div with columns?

Tags: html, css

Is there a specificity about div with columns ?
It seems like I can't get a background-color with `width:100%` on it.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="main">
   <div id="content">
      <div id="article"><!-- <p>text</p> --></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; color:white; background:transparent; }
#main { position:absolute; height:100%; top:0; left:0; }
#content { position:relative; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: auto; height: 100%; top:0; left:0; background:black; }
#article { border:10px solid yellow; float:left; width:100%; height:100%; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; font-size:25px; text-align:left; -webkit-column-width: 300px; -webkit-column-gap: 40px; -moz-column-width: 300px; -moz-column-gap: 40px; column-width: 300px; column-gap: 40px; background:green; }
```

Here is the JSFiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/53/

A part of the div is outside the yellow border.
How to resolve this ?

Comment: a part of which div is outside yellow border???

Comment: As you can see in the demo, a part of `#article` is outside.

Comment: The problem isn't getting the background-color on the columns, but getting the div to expand to fill its columns. Currently, it is 100% wide of the parent (as you specified it in CSS), but even if you do take that out it will still be 100% of parent. I couldn't find a way of making it automatically and horizontally expand to fit its contents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a solution with JS ?

Answer (score 0):

just remove `position:absolute` and `position:relative` from the main and content div the problem will be solved

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my project is an horizontal scroll website, as you can see in the demo. With these removes, the div isn't `height:100%` anymore...